# Instance '[Instance Name]' does not exist in the specified Category

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, performancecounter, multiple-instances

We are developing project for oracle database performance counter in webapi.The code for getting the instance name shown below

```
string pid = GetCurrentProcessId().ToString();

string instanceName2 =AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName.ToString().Replace('(', '[')
        .Replace(')', ']').Replace('#', '_').Replace('/', '_').Replace('\\', '_');


instName = instanceName2 + "[" + pid + "]";
```

and setting the instance in PerformanceCounter class

```
PerformanceCounter perfCounter = new PerformanceCounter();
perfCounter.CategoryName = catagoryName;
perfCounter.CounterName = counterName;
perfCounter.InstanceName = instName;
```

code for reading the counter value shown below

```
foreach (PerformanceCounter p in this.PerfCounters)
{                   
   string counterValue = string.Join("=", p.CounterName, p.NextValue());
    obj.textBox1.AppendText("\r\n" + counterValue);
}
```

when I trying to read the counter values getting exception like, Instance '[Instance Name]' does not exist in the specified Category.After opening the DB connection unable to detect instance name.